# Method design approach where method takes variable number of values for a parameter

Tags: java, arrays, list, oop, design-patterns

I have method that can take a single file name or array/list of files, and does some processing on them as follows:

```
public void methodName(String file, int arg2) {
...
}
```

OR

```
public void methodName(String[] files, int arg2) {
...
}
```

Lets say there is equal likely chance it will take single or list of files. What is the best design approach to this situations given no other restrictions?

1. Create method 1 and write wrapper around it to handle list of files

```
public void methodName(String file, int arg2) {
...
}
public void methodName2(String[] fileName, int arg2) {
    for(String fn : fileName) {
        methodName(fn, arg2);
    }
}
```

2. Create method 2 and write wrapper to handle single file instance

```
public void methodName(String[] files, int arg2) {
...
}
public void methodName2(String file, int arg2) {
    methodName(new String[]{file});
}
```

3. Accept single and multiple args through array

```
public void methodName(String[] files, int arg2){
...
}

methodName(new String[]{"fileOne"});
methodName(new String[]{"fileOne", "fileTwo"});
```

Option 3 seems bit crude when passing args; having to create array for single instance.

4. Maybe a different approach. Let's say var args are undesirable by changing parameter other.

What things should you consider now and for future maintainability?

Comment: I'm quite unsure what you mean by the option 2. Could you give code examples for every option? Thanks.

Comment: Added examples so it is clear what I meant.. Should've probably done it from start.

Comment: What do you mean by "_var args are undesirable by changing parameter other_"? What is _other_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 3 could be to use varargs, note that arg2 must come before files in the method declaration

```
public void methodName(int arg2, String... files) {
    for (String file: files) {

    }
}
```

Regarding options 1 and 2 they are basically the same but with small internal differences. You should take advantage of method overloading though and use the same method names, this will make a great advantage to the user of the public methods.

```
public void methodName(String file, int arg2) {
    ...
}

public void methodName(String[] file, int arg2) {
    ...
}
```

This is of course applicable to both option 1 and 2

Comment: Apologies forgot to add in question that this approach was not desirable.

Comment: @ManchuRatt Update answer with a suggestion regarding option 1 & 2

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might consider is not only maintability but also **testability**.

As I see it, **option 1** says

> I have a method `methodName` on a single file. If I have a list of files I'm able to apply this `methodName` sequentially on it.

You are just building natural extension `methodName2` built upon simpler functionality `methodName`.

Note that this is some kind of "*divide and conquer*" method.

---

**option 2** says:

> I have a method `methodName` on a list of `files`. If I have a single file, I'm able to create a list of files (single file) and call `methodName` on it.

Here we are trying to build simpler functionality from more complicated, which leads to creation of list of single file.

---

So **option 1** is definetely more natural.

It's better to **test** something works on a single thing, then you can be sure it will works on list of those things as well.